# SwiftUI Text not shrinking with .fixedSize()

Tags: swift, text, swiftui

I'm working on an app with a piece of large text with buttons underneath which I want to take up the same width as the text. My solution is to use a `VStack` with the `.fixedSize()` modifier:

```
VStack {
    Text(viewModel.timeString)
        .animation(nil)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .font(.system(size: 100, design: .monospaced))
        .padding(.vertical, -20)
    TimerActionsCompact(viewModel: viewModel) // the 3 buttons
}
.fixedSize()
```

This produces the result I want:

[image]

However, when the text becomes too big, it just goes off the screen instead of shrinking, even though I have `minimumScaleFactor` and `lineLimit` set.

I found that the problem was `.fixedSize()`, and removing it causing the text to shrink properly.

Am I doing something wrong, or could this be a bug with swiftUI? If so is there any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One possible way you can use frame modifier like this example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var string: String = "0.0"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(string)
            .font(.system(size: 100, design: .monospaced))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 80) // give your custom size here as you like!
            .background(Color.gray.cornerRadius(10.0))
            .animation(nil, value: string)
        
        Button("add") { string += String(describing: Int8.random(in: 0...9)) }.padding()
        
    }
    
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: This works to make the text shrink when it gets to big, but since it has a fixed size from due to the frame, the buttons don't adapt to be the same width as the text, defeating the point of the `.fixedSize()`

Comment: So you want the Buttons get shrink as well? that would be another issue and another question.

Comment: I just want the buttons to always be the same length as the text. But they shouldn’t shrink, since the text only shrinks when it gets longer, therefore staying the same width. If it’s a different issue do you know how I could solve it?

Comment: Yes, for sure I can solve it, but I am not sure if I understood what you really want.

Comment: All I want is for the buttons to be the same width as the text, like in my screenshot. If the text a character longer, the buttons should be that same length wider. That's what the `fixedSize()` modifier did. However, I also want the text to shrink when it becomes too wide to fit on the screen. This doesn't happen right away, the text can grow a few characters, and the buttons should grow with it, until it runs out of space and the size of the text has to decrease. But the `.fixedSize()` modifier prevented this from happening, and I understand why now, but I can't think of another way to do it

Comment: Hopefully this makes sense and thanks for the help!

Comment: I can tell you right now that forget about ‘.fixedSise()’ modifier. That modifier is not needed for your issue. The right question to ask would be, what is your view size situation? Is it pre setting size or it fill the all empty space as given?

Comment: Yeah I’ve realized that now. There was a hacking with swift articles that said you should use fixedSize to make views the same width but in this case it has some other side effects. The buttons fill all the space they are given. (They have a `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` modifier)

Comment: So you want Text take all available space and under Text the Buttons stay as you showed in picture and if Text string became longer than it can fits then it must shrinks in size while the Buttons keeps their size, right?!

Comment: Yes, but the buttons should grow and shrink to be the same width as the text.

Comment: Then for me it is a new issue or question. You can make a new question and explain what you want. This is my last comment here.

Comment: That was part of my original question though... Literally the first sentence: "...large text with buttons underneath which I want to take up the same width as the text"